# When did Palpatine gain an interest in Anakin?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious

Was it since the birth of Anakin? Or, after Anakin was accepted as a Jedi by the Jedi Council? Or, after some event when Anakin looked special?

Only canonical answers, please. No speculative answers...

Comment: @OghmaOsiris - Thanks for editing the title.  I much prefer the new phrasing.

Comment: The answer to this question uses a Legends source, but it sounds like you want a canon source only (as in, *not* Legends). Correct?

Comment: @Null: Well, you might have to wait a bit for a reply or better answer to be accepted.

Comment: @Ellesedil I know, but there's no way I'm going to remember to come back at that time!

Answer (score 17):

> “But tell me, Padawan Skywalker, how it feels to have become a member of such a revered group.”
>   “It’s like a dream come true, sir,” Anakin said in genuine sincerity.
>   “A dream come true ... Then you’ve long thought about the Jedi Order and about the Force.”
>   Anakin nodded. “I’ve always wanted to bring justice—”
>   “It’s not for you to decide your destiny, Anakin,” Obi-Wan said. “The Force will guide you.”
>   Palpatine smiled inwardly. Guide you to me, young
>   Skywalker.
>   **Dooku had talent, and could be a powerful placeholder.
>   But this seemingly guiless pleasant-faced boy, this Forceful boy, was the one he would take as his appretice, and use to execute the final stage of the Grand Plan.** Let Obi-Wan instruct him in the ways of the Force, and let Skywalker grow embittered over the next decade as his mother aged in slavery, the galaxy deteriorated around him, and his fellow Jedi fell to inextricable conflicts. He was too young to be trained in the ways of the Sith, in any case, but he was the perfect age to bond with a father figure who would listen to all his troubles and coax him inexorably over to the dark side.

From [*Darth Plagueis*](http://books.google.com/books?id=7sw1Qs17EoUC&lpg=PP1&ots=LX99TRIYbS&dq=%2aDarth%20Plagueis%2a&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=%2aDarth%20Plagueis%2a&f=false)

That was just after the battle of Naboo. So in fact Sidious chose Skywalker as his heir the first time they met.

Love at first sight. :)

Comment: Could you please cut down the length of your quote, and summarize its content for us? It would be best to provide a link to any sources you've quoted too.

Comment: That would be of course illegal.

Comment: @MarkBeadles He's citing he source right after the quote, it's from the recent book *Darth Plagueis*.

Comment: ALS, thanks for cutting down the quote. I confess I don't understand what would be illegal. I didn't ask you to link to a *full text* of the source.

Comment: @Keen It would be more helpful to provide a link than to just say "from Darth Plagueis".

Comment: Hold on a second.. Where's the `battle of Naboo` in the quote?

Comment: @SachinShekhar The climactic space and ground battle in Episode 1.

Comment: @Keen The answer says `That was just after battle of Naboo`. My concern: How did ALS say this? Plus, the whole quote seems meaningless which isn't explaining "when".

Comment: @SachinShekhar - It was in the book and in the movie.  Though I think the relevant quote "We will watch your career with great interest Padawan Skywalker" (or somthing like that) is missing from the answer to tie it all together.

Comment: I haven't read this book, but I've always been under the impression from the opera sceen in RotS that 1. Plagueis was Sidious's master, 2. Plagueis taught him how to create life via the Force, 3. Sidious killed his master, 4. Sidious engineered Anakin's "virgin birth" specifically to take as an apprentice. This, of course, is speculation on my part.

Comment: @MichaelItzoe Without spoiling too much, I will say that only 2 of those 4 are true.

Answer (score 8):

While the [other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/22941/31936) is correct, it's Legends canon now. *Darth Plagueis* is an amazing book and I highly recommend you read it, Legends or not.

As for canon, the only thing I can think about is the end of *The Phantom Menace*, when Palpatine says to young Anakin:

> And you, young Skywalker, we will watch your career with great interest.

Youtube clip with the quote:

Comment: There's a [clip on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67h8GyNgEmA) of that line. You were close. +1

Comment: I edited in the correct quote and the Youtube clip for you.

Comment: Thanks. I'm at work behind a proxy server and can't access youtube.